# How to show custom animation after uploading a document/image using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want the animation to look similar to
[what's shown in this Pinterest post](https://in.pinterest.com/pin/211880357457315713/?nic_v2=1a6cVli0Y).
I am unable to replicate as shown using the below starter script!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container mt-3">
  <form>
    <p> file:</p>
    <div class="custom-file mb-3">
      <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile" name="filename">
      <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
    </div> 
  </form>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Better check some of jQuery [upload plugins](https://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-file-uploads/) or [jQuery upload file](http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php).

Comment: thank you for helping me in better way